# Why does vim rely so heavily on compile-time feature configuration?

Tags: c, vim, neovim

I understand that one of the main vim's main goals are portability and customisation. Abundance of comments in the manual about things working differently on various problems does not surprise me. However, I don't understand why almost every feature can be disabled with a compile flag, what purpose does it serve? Wouldn't it be easier to be able to disable features in runtime, with some kind of configuration?

As far as I understand (I tried diving into vim code, but didn't write any patches), it makes the code base much more complicated, and that's exactly what Neovim developers are trying to remove. Why did vim developers follow this approach?

Comment: The short version of it?  Back in ye olde days people wanted to do things like put Vim on [floppy disks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk), or run it on [Commodore Amiga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga) machines.  Space was important.  However, people being people meant somebody's useless bloat was always somebody else's essential feature.  Thus the zillion compile flags.

Comment: So, build size? Did removing the features really reduce the binary size as much? Btw, if that's what it was, it seems like it would be a great answer and not just a comment.

Comment: Some flags also have to do with different build targets. Vim is an example of a program which runs on many platforms (shells would be another). It must provide replacements or customizations for things which may not be available or work differently on the target (screen addressing, memory allocation, inter process communication and so on).

Comment: Peter, as I already said in the answer, I understand the portability issue and flags that go from this. My question was specifically about feature flags. So, your point only explains features that wouldn't work correctly on all the platforms; however, to me it seems that majority of features you can switch off require the same platform capabilities.

Comment: Why don't you ask this question on the vim_dev mailing list? Or vim_use?

Comment: Vim still runs on DOS. How many programs today can claim that? Is this a useful feature? And is it worth the overhead? Perhaps, perhaps not...  You decide ... But that's the reason. Another reason is probably providing as much backwards compatibility as possible for those who want it (this is also why you still have to use `set nocompatible`).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think that portability was already discussed a couple of comments prior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several forces for having many flags (some of which have already been mentioned in the comments):

- portability: with quite different (and exotic, like DOS and Amiga) operating systems to support, different (GUI) libraries must be included, so there's a definite need for conditional compilation via `#ifdef`
- on many Linux distributions, a *tiny* build of Vim serves as the default implementation for `vi`; that one should *not* have any of the extended features
- it allows for utter flexibility: developers / packagers can mix and match freely (though I guess most will stick to the default tiny / big / huge feature bundles)

So, my (unofficial) guess is that a useful and necessary (see above) feature was increasingly used for more and more features as Vim grew and matured. Initially, this is good (consistency, a single mechanism to configure). When problems started to appear, it was too late to retroactively switch to a (better?) approach (like runtime configuration); the (development and testing) effort would now be prohibitive.

Comment: Vim HEAD almost certainly cannot run on 16-bit Amiga nor DOS. Bram hinted at this himself.